# How can I remove array columns with all null values?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say I have this array,

```
[
  ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh"],
  ["A"    , 1       , 2      , 3       , 4      , 5      , null     ],
  ["B"    , 1       , 2      , null    , null   , 5      , null     ],
  ["C"    , null    , 2.5    , 3       , 4      , 5      , null     ],      
]
```

Now, it's a mix of Strings, integers, floats/doubles, and null values. In the last column, every value is null, and I need to remove that column (ignore the fact that the first row isn't null).

That only way I can think to do this, is loop over the entire array (and sub arrays), and keep a boolean for each column stating whether all the values are null or not, and then loop over it all again, and if the column is entirely null, remove the indexes.

This to me seems really inefficient, and I'm wondering if there's a better way I can do this.

Just so you have an idea, the output array, needs to be like so.

```
[
  ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth"],
  ["A"    , 1       , 2      , 3       , 4      , 5      ],
  ["B"    , 1       , 2      , null    , null   , 5      ],
  ["C"    , null    , 2.5    , 3       , 4      , 5      ],      
]

// The "Seventh" column was removed due to all it's values being null.
```

I'm going to set up a jsfiddle example, and I'll edit the link in once done.

[Here's my rough proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/tomharto/p5uj8yz2/) for the looping idea I had.

Comment: I think you've got the right idea. No two ways around it: you have to check and then act.

Comment: You don't have to check the entire array, once all the bools hit true for content you can stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick

```
function remove(arr) {
   var toRemove = Array.apply(null, new Array(arr[0].length)).map(function(_, i){return i;});

   arr.slice(1).forEach(function(row){
      toRemove = toRemove.filter(function(index){//filter only values that left
         return row[index] === null;
      });
   });

  return arr.map(function(row){
      return row.filter(function(_, i){
        return toRemove.indexOf(i) < 0;
     });
  });
}
```

Comment: This works great, thanks! Now time to understand exactly what it does :p.